# How to safely pass an arbitrary text as parameter to a program in a shell script?

Tags: c, bash, sh, posix

I'm writing a GUI application for character recognition that uses Tesseract. I want to allow the user to specify a custom shell command to be executed with `/bin/sh -c` when the text is ready.
The problem is the recognized text can contain literally anything, for example `&& rm -rf some_dir`.

My **first** thought was to make it like in many other programs, where
the user can type the command in a text entry, and then special strings (like in `printf()`)  in the command are replaced by the appropriate data (in my case, it might be `%t`). Then the whole string is passed to `execvp()`. For example, here is a screenshot from qBittorrent:
[image]

The problem is that even if I properly escape the text before replacing `%t`, nothing prevents the user to add extra quotes around the specifier:

```
echo '%t' >> history.txt
```

So the full command to be executed is:

```
echo ''&& rm -rf some_dir'' >> history.txt
```

Obviously, that's a bad idea.

The **second** option is only let the user to choose an executable (with a file selection dialog), so I can manually put the text from Tesseract as `argv[1]` for `execvp()`. The idea is that the executable can be a script where users can put anything they want and access the text with `"$1"`. That way, the command injection is not possible (I think). Here's an example script a user can create:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1" >> history.txt
```

It there any pitfalls with this approach? Or maybe there's a better way to safely pass an arbitrary text as parameter to a program in shell script?

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  Are you asking about how your C program should pass arguments to a shell script, or about how a shell script should *handle* arbitrary arguments?  Or about something yet else?

Comment: I'm also lost by this description.  Code is more helpful to understand what you're trying to do, especially since this question is tagged as `[c]`.  In general, the way to pass arbitrary data into another program is with a pipe.

Comment: What's the problem with the user specifying `rm` as the command to run? Also, what data?

Comment: If you're letting the user specify an arbitrary command to execute, then the game is already over. Arbitrary code execution leads to arbitrary code execution. If you want to control or whitelist the *command* to execute while still allowing for arbitrary *arguments*, then that's a workable problem. The solution is to avoid letting the shell interpret your command line, by keeping all the arguments as distinct strings the whole way.

Comment: I updated the question. Hopefully, it's more clear now.

Comment: BTW -- thank you for thinking about this. People who don't are why we (as an industry) have command injection vulnerabilities everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## In-Band: Escaping Arbitrary Data In An Unquoted Context

***Don't do this. See the "Out-Of-Band" section below.***

To make an arbitrarily C string (containing no NULs) evaluate to itself when used in an unquoted context in a strictly POSIX-compliant shell, you can use the following steps:

- Prepend a `'` *(moving from the required initial unquoted context to a single-quoted context).*
- Replace each literal `'` within the data with the string `'"'"'`. These characters work as follows:

  1. `'` closes the initial single-quoted context.
  2. `"` enters a double-quoted context.
  3. `'` is, in a double-quoted context, literal.
  4. `"` closes the double-quoted context.
  5. `'` re-enters single-quoted context.
- Append a `'` *(returning to the required initial single-quoted context).*

This works correctly in a POSIX-compliant shell because the only character that is not literal inside of a single-quoted context is `'`; even backslashes are parsed as literal in that context.

However, this only works correctly when sigils are used only in an unquoted context (thus putting onus on your users to get things right), and when a shell is strictly POSIX-compliant. Also, in a worst-case scenario, you can have the string generated by this transform be up to 5x longer than the original; one thus needs to be cautious around how the memory used for the transform is allocated.

<sub>(One might ask why `'"'"'` is advised instead of `'\''`; this is because backslashes change their meaning used inside legacy backtick command substitution syntax, so the longer form is more robust).</sub>

---

## Out-Of-Band: Environment Variables, Or Command-Line Arguments

Data should only be passed *out-of-band* from code, such that it's never run through the parser at all. When invoking a shell, there are two straightforward ways to do this (other than using files): Environment variables, and command-line arguments.

In both of the below mechanisms, only the `user_provided_shell_script` need be trusted (though this also requires that it be trusted not to introduce new or additional vulnerabilities; invoking `eval` or any moral equivalent thereto voids all guarantees, but that's the user's problem, not yours).

#### Using Environment Variables

Excluding error handling (if `setenv()` returns a nonzero result, this should be treated as an error, and `perror()` or similar should be used to report to the user), this will look like:

```
setenv("torrent_name", torrent_name_str, 1);
setenv("torrent_category", torrent_category_str, 1);
setenv("save_path", path_str, 1);

# shell script should use "$torrent_name", etc
system(user_provided_shell_script);
```

A few notes:

- While values can be arbitrary C strings, it's important that the variable names be restricted -- either hardcoded constants as above, or prefixed with a constant (lowercase 7-bit ASCII) string and tested to contain only characters which are permissible shell variable names. (A lower-case prefix is advised because POSIX-compliant shells use only all-caps names for variables that modify their own behavior; see [the POSIX spec on environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), particularly the note that *"The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities"*).
- Environment space is a limited resource; on modern Linux, the maximum combined storage for both environment variables and command-line arguments is typically on the scale of 128kb; thus, setting large environment variables will cause `execve()`-family calls with large command lines to fail. Validating that length is within reasonable domain-specific limits is wise.

---

#### Using Command-Line Arguments:

This version requires an explicit API, such that the user configuring the trigger command knows which value will be passed in `$1`, which will be passed in `$2`, etc.

```
/* You'll need to do the usual fork() before this, and the usual waitpid() after
 * if you want to let it complete before proceeding.
 * Lots of Q&A entries on the site already showing the context.
 */
execl("/bin/sh", "-c", user_provided_shell_script,
  "sh",                 /* this is $0 in the script */
  torrent_name_str,     /* this is $1 in the script */
  torrent_category_str, /* this is $2 in the script */
  path_str,             /* this is $3 in the script */
  NUL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're runnng commands with even the possibility of user input making its way into them you **must** escape for the shell context.

There's no built-in function in C to do this, so you're on your own, but the basic idea is to render user parameters as either properly escaped strings or as separate arguments to some kind of execution function (e.g. [`exec` family](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp)).

Comment: I strongly disagree -- instead of trying to escape data to pass it inline with code, it should be passed out-of-band from that code, so no escaping is needed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's what I'm trying to say with the second part and `exec` which has options of avoiding escaping.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Why? That's purely a style preference. Shell escaping is trivial and not subject to botching.

Comment: @R.., the "why" is the long history of people and projects that get this "trivial" task wrong. I've found a few such exploitable bugs in the wild myself (years ago, now fixed, but one of them in a major Apache library and another in a tool intended to be used for remote execution of commands from a Java frontend).

Comment: @R.., ...POSIX escaping *is* pretty easy to do right, but the other thing to keep in mind is that not every shell implements only POSIX-baseline syntax; folks who try to be clever and only do the minimal amount of escaping needed can run afoul of extensions.

Comment: I'm with @CharlesDuffy that it's a lot harder to screw things up if no escaping is required. `execl` makes it possible to spell out arguments individually. This isn't a silver bullet, mind you, as you can exploit weaknesses in the target executable, but it's a lot safer than trying to escape and stuff into the shell, which itself presents even more attack vectors.

Comment: @R.., ...actually, thinking about it, I've also found shell injection bugs (despite *attempted* but faulty escaping code) more recently than that, but in a proprietary codebase I can't identify here. So -- trivial, yes; but the industry has lots of incompetence to go 'round -- as author of musl, you've surely seen how often "simple" things are botched by some of your project's competitors.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I think you're right that your preferred way is better (and I upvoted your answer) for OP's particular situation, which has the unusual requirement of being safe when a user who doesn't know what they're doing is writing the command line that the untrusted text would be injected into *and* the untrusted text is potentially malicious. But in general, quoting with single quotes and replacing any existing `'` character with `'\''` or `'"'"'` is completely safe. Any shell that broke this while purporting to be a Bourne/POSIX sh *extension* is just broken-by-design.